# Why is my webcam not recognized by QCameraInfo in Qt5 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, webcam, qt5

I want to list my available webcams using [this function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamerainfo.html#availableCameras) included in the `QCameraInfo` class in Qt 5, but when I check the returned list, I see that it's empty showing there's no webcam working on my computer. To check if my webcam is connected, I used [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) and [Kamoso](https://apps.kde.org/kamoso/) softwares, but both of them could recognize it showing it works well in these programs. I even checked if my webcam is connected using `lsusb` command, and the name of my webcam was listed showing it is connected.

It's worth mentioning that the function in the `QCameraInfo` class can recognize my webcam well on Windows 10 but I don't why not on Ubuntu 20.04.

So, I don't know why is this happening and I don't what to do to solve this problem. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt5 programming; but don't forget the link you provided is for Qt 5.15.5, and 20.04 or *focal* uses Qt 5.12.8 or the older LTS release of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved by insalling **libqt5multimedia5-plugins** following this post: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/127229/pyqt-qcamerainfo-availablecameras-is-empty.